# Understanding object inheritance and prototypes - new vs create method

Tags: javascript, inheritance

I created an example in which I try to figure out the main difference between two "new" and "create" methods. Could you check if my explanation is correct? Thank you very much!

So I have simplified the inheritance::

1. Using the NEW method: if I add a Person object, it will automatically inherit the methods and properties from both MANKIND and OBJECT

Prototype chain:

JAMES object -> Person.prototype -> Mankind.prototype--> Object.prototype

---

2. Using the CREATE method: if I add JACK using the Person object as a prototype

--> then it WON'T  inherit the methods and properties neither from MANKIND nor from OBJECT.

Prototype chain:

JAMES object -> Person.prototype X Mankind.prototype X Object.prototype

---

Is this correct? So I won't be able to run for example a body tempreature method or property on JACK, which belongs to the mankind object..

Thank you very much, I hope I understand it right :-)

Comment: Without showing your code, it's really hard to imagine what you refer to.

Comment: The theory is what I need now, not a working code. It's a theoretical question. If you know the answer, please share with me, thank you very much :(

Comment: No. I have no idea what you are talking about with "*the NEW method*" or "*add a Person object*". What do "*MANKIND and OBJECT*" refer to? What is "*JACK*"? There are many different ways to use the `new` operator or the `Object.create` method, with very different results, not all of which are desirable.